# Android Maps not initializing on 2g or slow internet connections

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

In one of my activity I am showing google map in fragment. It's working fine with 3g or high speed internet connection. But in 2g or very slow internet connection it's hang my mobile, And after some time I get 'not responding' message. Is there any way by which i can handle this situation?
here's the code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            InitializeClient();
            InitializeDB();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mqtt=new MQTT();
        try{
            if(ip==null){
                System.out.println("Mqtt Initialized in Maps Activity");
                ip="demo.aiotm.in:1883";
            }
            //mqtt.setHost("tcp://"+ip);
            mqtt.setHost("tcp://10.30.60.242:1883");
            connection = mqtt.blockingConnection();
            connection.connect();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private void InitializeClient() {

        try {
            //Initializing googleApiClient
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}




        if (this.mMap != null) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }else {System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Map Not Initialized :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;");}
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        }
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()||googleApiClient.isConnecting()){System.out.println("------------------------------------>Api is connecting<-----------------------------------");}


    }
```

the above is my initialization code for maps activity..!!, i hope this much code is enough

NOTE:- It's not a full code. I removed some of code for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

[getMapAsync()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) provides a callback **onMapReady** where you receive the googleMap.

On slow internet connection maybe it takes time to query the maps, so you can move the googleApiClient initialization in **onMapReady** callback and also the permission requests.

Your code should look something like this

```
@Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    LatLngBounds SINGAPORE = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(1.2729, 103.6066), new LatLng(1.3553, 104.0323));
    mGoogleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(SINGAPORE);
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mGoogleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 16, 500);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    } else {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    getGoogleApiClient();

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    final PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
            final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = locationSettingsResult.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    //All location settings are satisfied
                    displayMarker();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    //Location settings are not satisfied, but could be fixed by showing a dialog
                    try {
                        //Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult()
                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), FragmentSearchLocation.LOCATION_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    //Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```